# Htaccess multilanguages

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have a multi-languages, but since i change the structure of the url, i had to made some changes, but its not working, maybe someone can figure out what is missing:

My url looks like this:

http://example.com/jobs-country-city-title-123.html

and need to be like

http://example.com/en/jobs-country-city-title-123.html

or

http://example.com/es/jobs-country-city-title-123.html

Code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /(es|en|pt)/jobs-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ job.php?lang=$1&country=$2&city=$3&title=$4&id_job=$5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested, but perhaps

```
RewriteRule ^(es|en|pt)/jobs-([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ /job.php?lang=$1&country=$2&city=$3&title=$4&id_job=$5 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Just set this as a rule in my htaccess file, created a php page called job.php and it ran ok! Depending upon the values you expect within the title parameter you might need to tweak that part of the rule - for instance, if the title includes spaces or underscores etc etc